# Response.Buffer doesn't work

Tags: c#

I'm working on a windows form in which I ping a host.

For some reason, I cant get `Response.Buffer` to work. I tried using `HttpContext.Current`, and I also double checked I added a reference to both `System.Web`, and `System.Net.NetworkInformation`.

Here is the code :

```
Ping p = new Ping();
PingReply r;

String s = UserInput;

r = p.Send(s);

HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = false;

if (r.Status == IPStatus.Success)
{
    string got = "Ping to " + s.ToString() + "[" + r.Address.ToString() + "] successful - " + r.Buffer.Length.ToString() + " bytes in " + r.RoundtripTime.ToString() + " ms." + "\n";
    string ToSave = ToSave + got;
}
```

Comment: null reference exception? `HttpContext.Current` will be `null` for a WinForms application. Why don't you try one of the [MSDN Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: What do you want to achieve with that? I also thought HttpContext was used mostly for ASP.net.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "it doesn't work"? Are you getting a compile-time or runtime error? IF so, please post the error message.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do? HttpContext is for the ASP.Net pipeline not a desktop application, and it's response buffering is not related to an ICMP ping ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do does not make sense. Pinging a host is to check whether it is alive, not sending / receiving data, what I think you are trying to do.

When you want to communicate between two clients, then `TcpClient` is probably what you need. Take a look at the docs and demo [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

When just trying to check connectivity, try this:

```
Ping p = new Ping();
PingReply reply = p.Send("www.contoso.com");

if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Im trying to check for internet connection, and see if there is a problem : i ping the router, a wps bridge and an dns, to check where is the problem.